# Can I use the GPIO pins without a breadboard to run a motor?

Tags: gpio

[image]

Can this setup work. I am new to robotics and raspberry pi. I had the motor lying around previously. What I am trying to get is that when the raspberry pi boots up the motor should start spinning and work as a system fan cooler

Comment: Welcome, @HackNoobGod. Your picture is quite unclear, as the lighting isn't great and it makes it hard to see exactly what you've wired together. A clearer picture or a diagram would probably be helpful, and identifying the parts you're using (model name etc) will probably help you get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the motor permanently running connect it to a 5V and ground pin on the expansion header.

If you want to control the motor (on/off, change speed, change direction) you need to connect it via a motor driver board (or equivalent circuitry).  A motor driver board can be controlled by the Pi GPIO and in its turn can control the motor. Suitable motor driver boards can be bought from eBay for a few UK pounds.

It is not safe to connect a motor direct to the Pi GPIO (the 5V and 3V3 and ground pins are not GPIO).

Comment: https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/mc33886-raspberry-pi-motor-driver-board-raspberry-pi.html

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. It turns out that I didn't know about 5v pins and ground pins not being gpio. I tried an it worked

Answer (score 0):

**NO!**

A motor is producing a EMC that could kill your GPIO and in worst case your Raspberry Pi.

And the current needed to run the motor is probably exceediing the limit of the GPIO!

You need a motor driver circuit, example [image]